# installing nvidia drivers on ubuntu

Tags: drivers

Have a Asus laptop GL552/ ubuntu 18.04 and a 950gtx. How do i install nvidia driver to recovry my graphic card ? I had already downloaded a file "NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.48.run".

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu.com! In case you find an answer to help solve a problem don't forget to click either the grey ☑ or the up-pointing arrow/triangle to the left of the text.

Comment: Jean, change Your 'deduction' form *.run files to sources like https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa so to avoid unnecessary troubles with compiling *.run nVidia driver file, more safe

Answer (score 0):

Using the *.run installer makes your updates depend on manual operations.

I suggest you instead have a look in

> System Settings > Software and Updates > / Additional Drivers \

Selecting:

> (*) Using NVIDIA Binary Driver - ...

... in here, will have you get updates automatically, without manual intervention.

The updates might not happen for every bleeding edge driver release, but instead you have a stable hassle free time using the computer.

---

If you REALLY wish to install the *.run driver; make sure you put it in a place you can find it when using the recovery console; e.g. put it in the root home directory:

> `sudo -i`
>   `cd; mv /the/path/<...>/*.run .`

Then reboot into the recovery console and run the installer from there

> bash NVIDIA<...>.run

Due to the way this installs; you may, at a later point in time, encounter problems in case of kernel & gui driver (e.g. xorg) updates.

If that happens, the "easy" fix is to use the recovery console to
`--uninstall` the driver and then immediately
`--install` it again,
after having made sure you booted with the NEW software active (i.e. using the new kernel).

*Caveat: That strategy worked well on 14.04, haven't tried it since...*

**Note:**
`bash NVIDIA<...>.run --help | less`
**will tell you a lot.**